# Prove that a simple graph with $2n$ vertices and $n^2 +1$ edges contains a triangle for $n \ge 2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Prove that a simple graph $G$ with $2n$ vertices and $n^2 +1$ edges contains a triangle for $n \ge 2$.

I see it for $n = 2$ or $n = 3$ ... , but I fail to generalize it.

Comment: Note that the lower bound of $n^2+1$ edges is sharp since the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ has $2n$ vertices and $n^2$ edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a direct application of [Turán's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem).  See any common graph theory book for a proof.

> **Turán's Theorem**: The largest number of edges in a $K_{r+1}$-free graph with $n$ vertices is at most $$\frac{r-1}{r}\cdot\frac{n^2}{2}$$
>
> **Corrollary**: Any graph with $n$ vertices and $\frac{r-1}{r}\cdot \frac{n^2}{2}+1$ or more edges will necessarily contain a $K_{r+1}$ subgraph

Here, we have $r=2$ since we are searching for triangles, a $K_3$ subgraph.

Turán's theorem tells us that the most number of edges a triangle-free graph could have is $\frac{n^2}{4}$.

Since your problem statement defined the number of vertices as $2n$ instead of as $n$, we have that the most number of edges of a $2n$-vertex triangle-free graph is $\frac{(2n)^2}{4}=n^2$.  Hence your graph with $n^2+1$ edges must have a triangle.